# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Graphic Design breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                  5         18
Users destroyed                               1,347          0
Users contacted                                  21          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue           102      1,894
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue               30        332
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue        147      1,225
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue               28        855
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                78      3,991
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue              302      5,123
Tags merged                                       6          0
Tag synonyms proposed                             6          0
Tag synonyms created                              6          0
Revisions redacted                                1          0
Questions reopened                               54         12
Questions protected                              18         55
Questions migrated                               30          0
Questions flagged⁴                              279      9,996
Questions closed                                514      1,093
Question flags handled⁴                       1,519      8,756
Posts unlocked                                    6          6
Posts undeleted                                   9         94
Posts locked                                      9      1,788
Posts deleted⁵                                  700      3,711
Posts bumped                                      0      4,562
Escalations to the CM team                        2          0
Comments undeleted                               42          0
Comments flagged                                 83      1,131
Comments deleted⁶                             1,371      2,497
Comment flags handled                           485        729
Answers flagged                                  92      2,021
Answer flags handled                          1,740        373
All comments on a post moved to chat             18          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Comment: Why does this have a downvote without any comment? What is wrong with this post (apart from it not being a question)?

Comment: @PieBie yea thats just wierd, anyway the statistics is at first glance a but odd.

Comment: @Shog9 Any thoughts on how this compares to other sites/things we should take particular note of?